# iOS image quality improvement

Tags: ios, graphics

**Icons Are Pretty Right?**

I'm working on an UI update in an iOS app, and trying to make things look a bit better with some new icons- but I seem to be incapable of determining how to save an image correctly so that it looks good in the interface!

[image: Image Quality Demonstration]

As you can see from this image, if I include a white background with the image it looks great. If I take those same images and use an alpha background they look terrible! It appears that either the images aren't using the @2x correctly, or something else is going horribly wrong.

These images are either saved with GIMP as a png with alpha, or exported from inkscape, the originals are vector graphics. We get the same results from both avenues. I am using both a base imageName.png and imageName@2x.png for scaling.

Somehow, magically, I changed the a single image to greyscale in gimp, and changed the base size to 25px and it showed up with alpha correctly blended. Stock images from apple are also functioning correctly, so it absolutely seems to be something that I'm doing incorrectly when I'm saving the images.

**The Setup in XCode**

[image: Image Attributes]
[image: Image Details]

**Basic Questions**

Is there a certain bit depth, argb vs rgba format, or some other quirk that I need to know to get these images to show up correctly? Is there any way to verify that the program is loading the correct imageName@2x vs imageName? Is there some document that talks about integrated graphics (the [iconography documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Iconography.html) isn't very helpful on technical details)

**Actual Images**

With Background:

[image: SwirlBase]

Without Background:

[image: SwirlAlpha]

Answer (score -2):

I think you will find success if you just save the image at 4x the size you actually want and specify the size manually.